# Can I make google.map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt() actionListener?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I drawing grid on google maps with API.

[here is example.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-overlay?hl=de)

```
function CoordMapType(tileSize) {
  this.tileSize = tileSize;
}

CoordMapType.prototype.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
  var div = ownerDocument.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = coord;
  div.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
  div.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
  div.style.fontSize = '10';
  div.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
  div.style.borderWidth = '1px';
  div.style.borderColor = '#AAAAAA';
  return div;
};

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {lat: 41.850, lng: -87.650}
  });

  // Insert this overlay map type as the first overlay map type at
  // position 0. Note that all overlay map types appear on top of
  // their parent base map.
  map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(
      0, new CoordMapType(new google.maps.Size(256, 256)));
}
```

The above code was drawing grid on the map.

But I cannot add addActionListener(onclick, mouseover...) each grid cell.

How can I addActionListener to grid cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the example I just created on codepen [here](http://codepen.io/Lincecum/pen/grQwxr)

Hope it does help.

The transformation method is from google example [google example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates), you should try add eventListener on the map object not the div element.

```
function CoordMapType(tileSize) {
  this.tileSize = tileSize;
}

CoordMapType.prototype.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
  var div = ownerDocument.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = coord;
  div.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
  div.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
  div.style.fontSize = '10';
  div.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
  div.style.borderWidth = '1px';
  div.style.borderColor = '#AAAAAA';
  return div;
};

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {lat: 41.850, lng: -87.650}
  });

  map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    if(_INFO_WINDOW){
      _INFO_WINDOW.close();
      _INFO_WINDOW.setMap(null);
    }
    var scale = 1 << map.getZoom();
    var worldCoordinate = project(e.latLng);

    var tileCoordinate = new google.maps.Point(
      Math.floor(worldCoordinate.x * scale / TILE_SIZE),
      Math.floor(worldCoordinate.y * scale / TILE_SIZE));

    var content = '';
    content += 'lat: ' + e.latLng.lat() + "<br />";
    content += 'lng: ' + e.latLng.lng() + "<br />";
    content += 'tile Coord: ' + tileCoordinate;

    _INFO_WINDOW = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: content,
      position: e.latLng,
      map: map
    });
  });

  // Insert this overlay map type as the first overlay map type at
  // position 0. Note that all overlay map types appear on top of
  // their parent base map.
  map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(
      0, new CoordMapType(new google.maps.Size(256, 256)));
}

function project(latLng) {
  var siny = Math.sin(latLng.lat() * Math.PI / 180);

  // Truncating to 0.9999 effectively limits latitude to 89.189. This is
  // about a third of a tile past the edge of the world tile.
  siny = Math.min(Math.max(siny, -0.9999), 0.9999);

  return new google.maps.Point(
      TILE_SIZE * (0.5 + latLng.lng() / 360),
      TILE_SIZE * (0.5 - Math.log((1 + siny) / (1 - siny)) / (4 * Math.PI)));
}

var _INFO_WINDOW = null;
var TILE_SIZE = 256;

initMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to add a clickHandler per tile. What you would have to do is a little workaround:

- Add a clickHandler to the map
- get the LatLng of the ClickEvent
- use the map projection `map.getProjection()` to convert the coordinates to world coordinates / point plane
- use your actual zoom level to calculate the pixel coordinates `pixelCoordinateX = parseInt(worldCoordinateX * Math.pow(2, zoom), 10)` (do the same for y)
- Divide the pixelCoordinates by the tile size (256 in your case): `tileNoX = parseInt(pixelCoordinateX / 256, 10)`. Now you should have your tile number.

Does this help you?